# Redirect to URL with variable inside php

Tags: php, variables, url

I am trying to make a signon page, where people just type in their usernames and get redirected to a url with their username as a variable.
This should all happen without getting something from another file.

Just like, the form's action would be the php to redirect with the variable from the submit button.

I am not very much into php programming but know basic HTML and some jquery, so it would be awesome if there was anyone who could give me the code to copy/paste into my index file.

Thanks

UPDATE:
As it is, i have the login system up and running, but it is located in the users own director.
So the form on the main page should load the username and paste it as an other directory on the server.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: if you are not into php programming but you want to create a signon page, consider paying someone to do that for you because this is not a free "others will do the work for me" plattform http://www.freelancer.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']!="")
        {
            if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!="")
            {
             header('Location: some_other_page.php?username='.$_POST['username']);
             exit;
            }
        }

    ?>

    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
        <input name='username' type='text' value='' placeholder='Insert username here'>
        <input type='submit' value='Go' name='Go'>
        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='do_redirect'>
    </form>
```

Comment: good :) for a better use, check the value of the hidden field if it's equal to your rule ( $_POST['action'] =='do_redirect' ) instead of $_POST['action']!=''

Answer (score 1):

Use the form as a "GET"!

```
<form action="login.php" method="get">
</form>
```

Then your input name will be the variable. So:

```
<form action="login.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="username"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

This form will redirect to:

```
login.php?username=The username which you gave
```

Comment: Alright, that was the function that i was looking for, but i need it to redirect to the directory with the username
So that the url would be this www.domain.com/(username)

Answer (score 0):

On submit of signon page after entering correct username and password you can set your username in `$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username']`.
And to redirect to another page you need to write below line:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/dashboard');
exit;
```

Example:   save below file as login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
        //// you need to write some code over here to get password verification from database based on username is entererd
        //// i.e. $data = $db->mysql_query();
        if()//write some code here if password is verified then allow to login and enter into system
        {
            $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
            header('Location: http://www.example.com/dashboard');
            exit;
        }
}
?>
```

Its only the logic. you need to make some changes and write code at your end.